# Send text via chosen messenger

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I need to grant user an ability to choose a preinstalled on the phone messenger (SMS, Mail, Viber, WhatsApp, Skype etc) and send a text message with it.

Is there a way on Android and iOS to do that without custom views? Only can find a ways to send message via specific app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        String txt = "text to share"; 
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject"); 
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txt);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, LifeStyle. And the final implementation for Xamain:

[iOS]

```
public void Send(string message)
        {
            var activityItems = new[] { NSObject.FromObject(message) };
            var activity = new UIActivityViewController(activityItems, null);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(activity, true, null);
        }
```

[Android]

```
public void Send(string message)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
            intent.SetType("text/plain");
            intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "Subj");
            intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, message);

            _targetActivity.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Title"), _resultCode);
        }
```